# How to display twitter feeds based on users in django & tweepy?

Tags: django, twitter, django-models, django-views, tweepy

I want to show twitter data based on twitter username in my 
template (Tweepy) but I don't know how to send data from my **models** into my **views**.

The content of `models.py` is:

```
<pre>
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings    

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
# Create your models here.
class Feed(models.Model):
    owner             = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feed              = models.CharField(max_length=211, blank=True, null=True)
    twitter           = models.CharField(max_length=211, blank=True, null=True) # this is the twitter username which the user can enter and be sent to the views to api.get_user(twitter)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.feed
</pre>
```

The content of `views.py` is:

```
<pre>
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .tweet import *
from .models import Feed


def feed(request):
    api = tweepyapi(request)
    user = api.get_user(twitter) # I want this portion to be dynamic.
    findfriends = user.friends()
    return render(request, 'feeds/feeds.html', {
        'user': user,
        'findfriends': findfriends
    })

</pre>
```

Comment: what is twitter supposed to be? username ? and by dynamic you want to get the twitter detail for current logged in user ?

Comment: @SumeetKumar Yes, by twitter I meant twitter username. Actually I want  the users to enter their twitter username and whenever someone sees their profile, they can see the twitter feed and details of the specified user on their profile.

Comment: `Feed.objects.filter(owner=request.user)` is for generating current user timeline feed ? if so then don't you think view for generating current user feed and the view for visiting user should be different?

Comment: @SumeetKumar Sure, My mistake, I forgot to delete from previous test. Any solution about how should I go about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the answer I posted, let me know if that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you have Profile model related to User model via one-to-one relation

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    twitter_username = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        context = {
            'id':self.id,
            }
    return reverse("viewprofile", kwargs=context)
```

and in your template, we provide a link to user's profile as

```
{% for user in user_list %}
<a href="{% user.profile.get_absolute_url %}">{{ user.get_full_name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

now assuming you are passing `id` of user in `get_absolute_url`, your url will look like

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.feed, name="viewprofile")
```

and then in your view

```
def feed(request,id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile,user__id=id )
    api = tweepyapi(request)
    user = api.get_user(profile.twitter_username)
    findfriends = user.friends()
    return render(request, 'feeds/feeds.html', {
        'user': user,
        'findfriends': findfriends
    })
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: happy to help you mate :)

Comment: Yes I did! At the first attempt! but I am new here and it is not shown yet till I reach 15 reputation